# How to fetch the accounts based on a value checkbox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript, dynamic-binding, array, aura-iteration

I have a dynamic checkbox generator which is bound by city on the account which works fine all cities are rendered with a corresponding checkbox. When I select the checkbox a city is added to a list selection.

What I want to achieve is when a checkbox is selected to show all the records related to the city of that particular checkbox. When I select another checkbox the records related to this city should be added to the list. I currently have the following:

Component

```
    <aura:attribute name="selectedvalues" type="string" />
<aura:attribute name="SelectedCity" type="List[]" />
<aura:attribute name="CheckboxValue" type="Boolean" default="false" />
<aura:attribute name="myBool" type="Boolean" default="false"/>

<aura:attribute name="selectedCities" type="Account[]" default="[]" description="All accounts" />

<div class="container">       
    <div>
        <div style="background-color: #7f7e8a;height: 20px;"></div>       
        <aura:iteration var="a" items="{!v.allaccounts}" indexVar="indx">
            <ui:inputCheckbox aura:id="checkbox" 
                              text="{!a.account}"
                              name="{!indx}"
                              label="{!a.BillingCity}" 
                              change="{!c.selectoptionvalue}"
                              class="myCheckbox"/><br/>  
        </aura:iteration>
```

Javascript

```
selectoptionvalue: function(component, event, helper) {
    var selected = [], checkboxes = component.find("checkbox");
    if(!checkboxes) {   // Find returns zero values when there's no items
        checkboxes = [];
    } else if(!checkboxes.length) { 
        checkboxes = [checkboxes];
    }
    checkboxes
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.get("v.value"))    // Get only checked boxes
    .forEach(checkbox => selected.push(checkbox.get("v.label")));   // And get the labels
    component.set("v.selectedCities", selected);    // Set to display
}
```

I tried

```
 component.set("v.SelectedCity",
    component.get("v.accountsSel").filter(account => account.selected));
```

Instead of

```
component.set("v.selectedCities", selected);
```

This does not render the accounts

Update
I tried applying the suggested solution as follows:

```
checkboxes
        .filter(checkbox => checkbox.get("v.value"))    // Get only checked boxes
        .forEach(checkbox => selected.push(checkbox.get("v.label")));   // And get the labels
        component.set("v.selectedCities", selected);    // Set to display

        console.log('v.selectedCities:'+  selected);
        console.log('v.component.get("c.getAllAccounts"):'+ component.get("c.getAllAccounts"));

        console.log('filteredAccounts '+ filteredAccounts);
        var filteredAccounts = component.get("c.getAllAccounts").filter(account => selectedCities.indexOf(account.BillingCity) > -1);
        console.log('filteredAccounts '+ filteredAccounts);
```

Running a debug came up with:

> v.selectedCities:Burlington
>
> v.component.get("c.getAllAccounts"):SecureAction: [object Object]{
>    key: {"namespace":"c"} }
>
> filteredAccounts undefined

It seems like the filtered accounts returns empty which I don't get as selectedCities does return a selection.

Comment: Please take some time to learn more about [Lightning](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/lex_dev) and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript). I've written up a [demo application](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/75ddb362065d6da2e9801b7f8fb78a68) you can learn from, but you really do need to take some time to study.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the list of accounts using an array:

```
    var filteredAccounts = component.get("v.allAccounts")
        .filter(account => selectedCities.indexOf(account.BillingCity) > -1);
```

Comment: So how do I apply this in javascript: checkboxes
    .filter(checkbox => checkbox.get("v.value"))    // Get only checked boxes
    .forEach(checkbox => selected.push(checkbox.get("v.label")));   // And get the labels
    component.set("v.selectedCities", selected);    // Set to display
    var filteredAccounts = component.get("v.allAccounts").filter(account => selectedCities.indexOf(account.BillingCity) > -1);   trows an error: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: @Thomas That's a null-pointer error. You need to make sure you're using the correct names. Did you go through the trailhead I recommended for you?

Comment: Yes i did, am new to javascript so in javascript I dont know how to fill selectedCities.indexOf

Comment: @Thomas Look at the code I wrote. It's a full, working, copy-paste example for you to work from.

Comment: Okay thx I think ill have to look further in the javascript part as when paste you code it gives me:Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined] and I dont see yet how to define or fit in the selectedCities. I woudl think his would have to be v.selectedCities..indexOf But thanks for so far.

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me filteredAccounts as undefined? Seem my update above.